# Are all points of interest and vistas in Lion's Arch accessible at the moment?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I can't reach last Vista and last point of interest in Lion's Arch city.

The Vista is located to the east from Bloodcoast Ward and the point is a bit to the north from Eastern Ward.

I'm starting to suspect they are inaccessible at the moment. I tried to ask using in-game chat and after a positive answer, that yes - they are accessible, there was a comment, that they were before "fixing the bugs".

Could someone please shed some light on this and give pointers how to get there, if it's possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, they are all available. The POI you're missing is called the Lost Grotto. It's tricky because the entrance to the area is across the map. I've marked the area you need to start with a red X. Head to those docks and then in between them, underwater, you'll find a tunnel.

Swim through that tunnel and follow the way through across the zone to find the Lost Grotto.

> It's a secret base for the Order of Whispers.

[image: POI]

You can also check out this youtube video:

The Vista you are missing is another one that is tricky to get. Take the Farshore Waypoint and run up to Tokk's Mill. At the door, you need to jump on on the straw piles to the roof, then drop down behind them. There's a tunnel/door hidden by some hanging vines to the right after you jump down. You'll need to climb some more rocks and then you'll see the Vista.

You can see this process in the following video:

Answer (score 1):

There are two vista west of the Bloodcoast Ward teleport. The first (nearest) is at the top of a tower, easy to get. The other is at the mill. The point of interest should be no problem, but the vista is tricky.

You have to jump on straw piles to get on a roof. Drop off the other edge into a small square. Don't jump the other straw pile, but look for a passage hidden by plants. The follow the corridor. Again, after reaching a rock, you will find a hidden passage behind it. Then you have to go up, jumping on different rocks.

If you want, you can go through the big stone mouth to reach the pirate's jumping puzzle. Beware, it's tricky not to die of the fall.